# CUDA - copy OpenGL rendered image to 2D array

Tags: opengl, multidimensional-array, rendering, cuda

Is it possible, to render a scene using OpenGL and than somehow copy rendered image to, for example, 2D array using CUDA? I'd need to place a result in `bool picture[resX][resY]` array, where true = coloured pixel, false = empty space.

Thanks is advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You could render to a PBO in OpenGL and then subsequently map this to a CUDA texture. Have a look at the OpenGL interop documentation for some pointers